# windows Azure weird behaviour while saving entity into windows Azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Im saving batch of entity into Azure Table Storage, For some of the entity it save perfectly into table storage for same table . But some of the records, Table storage is throwing exception below.

ErrorMessage:An error occurred while processing this request.,InnerExceptionMessage:

  `OutOfRangeInput`
  48:One of the request inputs is out of range.
RequestId:f72230dd-55ea-4bc9-92b5-ca576af64324
Time:2013-01-05T07:16:19.4614968Z

Has any 1 came across the above error.

-Mahender

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @knightpfhor answer:

"**48**" in your error message indicates that there's an issue with entity #48 in your batch. Apart from the possible culprits mentioned above, please check the PartitionKey value for that entity. All entities in a batch must have same PartitionKey value. Also check if you're including same entity twice in your batch. An entity (i.e. unique PartitionKey/RowKey combination) can only appear once in a batch.

It may also be a good idea to trace the raw data sent to storage using Fiddler. Tracing the request/response through Fiddler will help you pinpoint the error.

Finally check this link for more information on entity group transactions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means exactly what it says, for some of your records have values that are not able to be saved because they're out of range.  The common culprits are usually a PartitionKey or RowKey with an invalid value or you're trying to save a type that isn't supported by table storage.  For information about what you can use, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When using the azure table rest api to query entities in winjs windows store app, I got this error and hit here while searching for the error. For me this happened because of silly mistake when changing code to form xhr request for storage emulator.

The bug in the code to calculate authorization header gave authorization header as `SharedKey devstoreaccount1/devstoreaccount1: <computed key>` whereas it should have been `SharedKey devstoreaccount1: <computed key>`. Because of the '/' character in the storage account name, this error was raised.

**Sidenote**: During authorization header calculation, stringToSign has CanonicalResource. CanonicalResource to query all entities in logs table for azure emulated storage is `/devstoreaccount1/devstoreaccount1/logs()` where for azure myaccount storage account is `/myaccount/logs()`. note the repetition of storage account twice for emulated storage.